# eigenvalues of fitted value?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, regression, projection-matrices

Let a $m\times n$ full-column matrix be $A$. Also, denote $m\times m$ diagonal matrix as $D$.

Define $P(A)D=A(A'A)^{-1}A'D$ as the orthogonal projection of $D$ onto the column space of $A$, or "fitted value" in regression term. Note that $(A'A)$ is full rank, so $P(A)$ always exists.

I'm wondering how the eigenvalues of $P(A)D$ are determined. Can we use the fact that $D$ is already a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @philip Can you explain me how my problem is related to the proof about diagonalization?

Comment: What you're doing is looking at square matrices $P$ and $D$, idempotent and diagonal respectively, and asking if there's a shortcut to compute the eigenvalues of $PD$. I'm pretty sure the answer is, no there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that the positive eigenvalues of $P(A)D$ are diagonal elements of $D$.  Consider e.g.
$$P(A) = \pmatrix{8/9 & -2/9 & -2/9\cr
                 -2/9 & 5/9 & -4/9\cr
                 -2/9 & -4/9 & 5/9\cr}, \ D = \pmatrix{a & 0 & 0\cr 0 & b & 0\cr 0 & 0 & c}$$
Then $P(A)D$ has characteristic polynomial $${t}^{3}- \left(\frac89 a +\frac59 b + \frac59 c\right)t^2+ \frac{4ac+bc+4ab}{9} t
$$
and none of $a,b,c$ are roots of this.

Comment: Thank you! If I ask you more, when the eigenvalues of $P(A)D$ becomes the distinct elements of $D$? Now I see from you answer that it's generally not always the case, but I found some cases where it holds.

Comment: Although I found some cases where it holds, the problem is I don't know what condition of $A$ will lead this property and WHY it holds. :(

Comment: If $P(A)$ and $D$ commute, they can be jointly diagonalized, and then it's true.